# Unit and Counit Maps of Adjunction Pair $(f^{-1}, f_*)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces $X,Y$, let $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf on $X$ and $\mathcal G$ sheaf on $Y$. It is known that the [Inverse image functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image_functor) $f^{-1} : {\bf Sh}(Y) \to {\bf Sh}(X)$ and [Direct image functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_image_functor) $f_{*} : {\bf Sh}(X) \to {\bf Sh}(Y)$ are adjoint, therefore there exist canonical morphisms of sheaves

$$\mathcal G\to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G\quad (1),\qquad f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F\quad (2)$$

In general neither the unit map (1) nor counit (2) is isomorphism. I'm interested in the case where $f$ is injectve. What can we say about maps (1) and (2) for the cases $f$ injective and ...

(a) open inclusion $f: U \hookrightarrow Y$, i.e. $f$ continuous with open $U \subset Y$
(b) closed inclusion $f: C \hookrightarrow Y$, the same with closed $C \subset Y$
(c) injective only $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$

In most testbooks $X$ and $Y$ are additionally endowed with structure of ringed spaces and (a) respec. (b) are extended to open respec. closed immersions, but I not think that it is neccessary here to bulk up $X$ and $Y$ with this additional structure.

Question: What can we say about unit (1) & counit maps (2) in cases (a), (b) & (c)? When are they isomorphisms, when surjective or injective?

Since $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal F$ are sheaves, it suffice to look at stalks, let $x \in X, y \in Y$. Then the the stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $x$ is

$$\mathcal F_x= \varinjlim_{U \in \mathcal{O}(X) \ : \ x \in U}\mathcal F(U) $$

About $f^{-1}\mathcal G$ two important facts are known: the stalk is easy to compute: $(f^{-1}\mathcal G)_x= \mathcal G_{f(x)}$ and if $f: U \hookrightarrow Y$ open inclusion like in (a) then $f^{-1}\mathcal G = \mathcal G \vert _U$.
For $f_*\mathcal F$ it's harder. The stalk formula says

$$ (f_*\mathcal F)_y  = \varinjlim_{V \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ y \in Y}\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V))  $$

If $f: C \hookrightarrow Y$ closed inclusion as in (b), then $ (f_*\mathcal F)_y= \mathcal F_y$ if $y \in F(C)$ and zero elso. If $f: U \hookrightarrow Y$ open inclusion, then $ (f_*\mathcal F)_y= \mathcal F_y$ if $y \in f(U)$ as before, but I can't find an argument why $ (f_*\mathcal F)_y=0$ if $y$ is not in the image. It can happen that every open $V \subset Y$ intersects non trivially with $U$. Can we say else something interesting about $ (f_*\mathcal F)_y$?

Finally, let's calculate the stalks of $f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G$ and $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F$. We obtain

$$(f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G)_y = \varinjlim_{V \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ y \in Y}f^{-1}\mathcal G(f^{-1}(V))\quad (1) \ \ \qquad (f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F)_x = \varinjlim_{V \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ f(x) \in V}\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V)) \ \ (2)$$

We conclude for (2) because $f(x)$ is obviously always contained in the image of $f$, that $(f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F)_x= \mathcal F_x$. Therefore if I'm not mistaken, then (2) should be for all cases (a), (b) & (c) an iso, yes?

For (1), if $y= f(x)$ in the image, then $(f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G)_y= \mathcal G_y$. If not, then we can at least say that for $f$ closed inclusion (b), if $y \not \in f(X)$, then $(f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G)_y=0$, so (1) is at least in this case always surjective.

Is what I wrote before true? Can we say something more about cases (a) & (c) for unit map (1)?

Comment: No this is not true that $\mathcal{G}\to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is surjective. As a counter example, take $X=(0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1]$ with the obvious inclusion and $\mathcal{G}=f_!\mathbb{Z}_X$ the extension by zero. Then $f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}=f_*\mathbb{Z}_X$ has a non trivial stalk at $y=0$.

Comment: Also, if $f$ is injective, even bijective, $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ might not be an isomorphism. You need at least that $X$ is endowed with the subspace topology.

Comment: @Roland: 
about $\mathcal{G}\to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ (1): so 
your counterexample with $f$ embedding $X=(0,1]$ as open subset 
into $Y=[0,1]$ shows that (a) not imply that
(1)  is
surjective. So obviously (c) also not implies surjectivity of (1),
only (b) (with $f$ closed inclusion) does it, right? 
Can we conclude injectivity of (1) from (a)? In your example 
with $\mathcal{G}=f_!\mathbb{Z}_X$ (1) is injective, since
$f_*\mathbb{Z}_X=\mathbb{Z}_Y$, unless I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: about (2): we have 
$  (f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F)_x = \varinjlim_{V \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ f(x) \in V}\mathcal F(f^{-1}(V)) $

and it equals $(\mathcal F)_x$ only if the system
$\{V \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ f(x) \in V\}$ is cofinal 
in $\{U \in \mathcal{O}(X) \ : \ x \in U\}$, and that's 
only the case if as you said $X$ has the 
subspace topology coming from $Y$, otherwise $X$ could 
have finer topology, and (2) might be not an isomorphism.
That's the argument which fully determine when (2) 
is isomorphism, right?

Comment: No, $\mathcal{G}\to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is not injective (take for example $X=(0, 1)$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and look at the stalk at $2$.

Comment: @Roland: for $\mathcal{G}$ you take in this example again $f_!\mathbb{Z}_X$? But at $2$ then the map $\mathcal{G}\to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is trivially injective in $2$ since $(f_!\mathbb{Z}_X)_2=0$ and since stalks after sheafification not change

Comment: No, I take any sheaf which has a non trivial stalk at 2

Comment: right, I see, thank you!

Comment: I think what you said about $f^{-1}f_ *\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ is right. I am actually surprised that I never read that before, so I am afraid I am missing something, but I think it is ok.

Comment: in 4th comment I made a mistake: I wanted to write ...only if the system $\{f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{O}(Y) \ : \ f(x) \in V\}$ is cofinal in $\{U \in \mathcal{O}(X) \ : \ x \in U\}$ , then (2) is iso

Comment: You mean $\{f^{-1}(V) : V\in \mathcal{O}(Y) \text{ and }f(x)\in V\}$, but yes, I understood.